# scala implicit identity

Tags: scala, identity, implicit

Take a database transaction:

```
def create(model: Model, orderNum: String) = {
  db.handle withSession { implicit ss: Session=>
    ss.withTransaction { // auto commit now set to false
      val result = for {
        uid <- repo.user.create(model)
        mid <- repo.membership.create(uid)
        oid <- repo.orders.create(model, uid, orderNum)
      } yield uid
      result fold( 
        e=> { ss.rollback; Left(e) }, 
        s=> { Cache.remove("member.directory"); Right(s) } 
      )
    }
  } 
}
```

If the repository user create implementation takes an implicit Session, *is it the same* Session as the withTransaction enabled Session above, or is implicit value "is a" rather than "is the" identity?

```
def create[T <: User](t: T)(implicit ss: Session) = // what Session is this?
  for {
    uid <- either( Users.insert( Users(t) ), i18n("user not created") )
    ur  <- either( UserRoles.insert( UserRole(uid, t.role) ), i18n("user role not created") )
  } yield uid
```

I could pass in the Session explicitly `repo.user.create(model)(ss)` and have create take an explicit Session, but am curious to know if more concise/convenient implicit approach provides the same outcome, *the* transaction enabled session.

Answer (score 1):

If I correctly understood you, you are using ScalaQuery and you want to have your method working also when the user provide the session from outside.

> def withSession
> [T] (f: ⇒ T): T Run the supplied thunk with a new session and
> automatically close the session at the end.
>
> def withSession [T] (f:
> (Session) ⇒ T): T Run the supplied function with a new session and
> automatically close the session at the end.

Both of these are creating a new transaction, so the way I would go is to use an Optional[Session] as implicit and default it to None

```
  def onProvidedOrCreatedSession[K](f: Session => K)(session:Option[Session]) = {
    session match {
      case Some(s) => f(s)
      case None => db.withSession { f }
    }
  }

  def create(model: Model, orderNum: String)(implicit session:Option[Session]=None){
    onProvidedOrCreatedSession( 
      implicit s => s.withTransaction {  val x = 10 }
    )(session)  
     
  }
```

Comment: +1, interesting. Am trying, as you can see, to run queries outside of the local transaction block by passing in the session implicitly to external query methods. By passing the session explicitly (what I'm actually doing in my "real" code), I was under the impression that ScalaQuery would use the explicitly passed session (that should have auto commit set to false). I did run some tests with explicit session passing and a failure at any point in the local transaction block rolls back all executed queries

Comment: Looked at SQ source again, you are correct; however, I am not using withSession or withTransaction in the external query methods; they receive the already existing transaction enabled session, which must be why, on failure, the local transaction block rolls back all the externally executed queries

Comment: This is correct . If you rum multiple queries inside a single transaction and one fails, all are rolled back. This is the atomicity feature in the Acid

Comment: withTransaction sets auto commit to false, so you are correct in the general case (i.e. when one throws an exception on query failure); however, in my example you have to explicitly rollback as any exception that occurs is caught and logged, returning Either[Why-Fail, Success]. Given that no exception is thrown, if a failure does occur and I don't rollback, when the withTransaction block exits SQ would commit any queries that were successfully executed.

Comment: Can you explain a little bit better the behaviour you would like with regard to transaction handling so I can improve my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if the following is a faithful abstraction of what you are trying to do, but I hope it helps:

```
class Store(var x: Int) {
  def flip() { x = -x }
}

object M1 {
  implicit val store2 = new Store(2)

  def create(s: String) = {
    implicit val store3 = new Store(3)

    { implicit store: Store => 
        println("[M1.create] store.x = " + store.x)
        store.flip()
        M2.create("tummy")
        println("[M1.create] store.x = " + store.x)
    }
  }
}

object M2 {
  implicit val store4 = new Store(4)

  def create(s: String)(implicit store: Store) = {
    println("[M2.create] store.x = " + store.x)
    store.flip()
  }
}

M1.create("dummy")(new Store(1))
```

The output is:

```
[M1.create] store.x = 1
[M2.create] store.x = -1
[M1.create] store.x = 1
```

- The `new Store(1)` that is explicitly passed to `M1.create` is forwarded to `M2.create`
- The additional implicit stores `store2, store3, store4` are apparently ignored by the compiler.